# Swift iOS HTTP POST from background refresh possible?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, background, urlsession

I'm new to Swift, SwiftUI and native iOS development. I know C# well and professionally develop apps with Xamarin.

Currently I'm developing a native iOS app with a watch extension using Xcode 14 and SwiftUI. Everything is going well except for one thing...

A short description:

- The App starts with a login screen where the user can enter username and password.
- I'm fetching an OAuth2-Token via HTTP-POST with a URLSession DataTask.
- Then I'm saving the refresh token for later renewal (the access token expires after 1h and I can't change that because it's a 3rd party API).
- After that I'm fetching data from the REST-API with HTTP-GET (also with URLSession DataTask), authorizing with the acquired access token.
- Then I'm showing the results in my view and transfer it to the watch where some dara is also displayed.

That all works fine!

When I put my app in background, a background refresh task is scheduled where I fetch the newest data whenever iOS let's me do it in the background. - Even this is working (including transfer to the watch).

But when the token expires and I try to renew it via POST (using the refresh token) **from background** my background thread stops at that point. I need to bring the app to front to resume the thread and fetch the new token. - Everything tested while debugging my iPhone (not the simulator).

What am I doing wrong? For background refresh I'm using a URLSession.background instance with delegate.

Since the last two days I'm penetrating google to find a solution for my problem but none of them are working… I even think that I'm the only one with that problem because I can't find anything about POSTing from background via DataTask.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

For clarification, here are some code snippets to describe the problem better.

Entry-Point:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = AppViewModel()

    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if !self.viewModel.initialized {
                StartupView()
            } else if !self.viewModel.loggedIn {
                LoginView(appViewModel: self.viewModel)
            } else {
                MainView(appViewModel: self.viewModel)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            if newPhase == .background {
                viewModel.scheduleBackgroundRefresh()
            }
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh(AppViewModel.BG_REFRESH_IDENTIFIER)) {
            await viewModel.performBackgroundRefresh()
        }
    }
}
```

How I schedule the background refresh:

```
func scheduleBackgroundRefresh() {
    let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: AppViewModel.BG_REFRESH_IDENTIFIER)
    request.earliestBeginDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(5.0 * 60.0)
    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        print("Background-Task scheduled!")
        // e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"<MyIdentifier>"]
    } catch let ex {
        print("Background-Task schedule error:\n\(ex.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

What the background refresh does:

```
func performBackgroundRefresh() async {
    if self.vehicleToUseForBackgroundRefresh == nil {
        return
    }
    var newCarState: CarStateModel? = nil
    var occuredEx: Error? = nil
    do {
        if !(self.psa.accessToken?.expired ?? true) {
            // Fetch data with HTTP GET, only if the token hasn't expired.
            newCarState = try AppViewModel.loadCarState(for: self.vehicleToUseForBackgroundRefresh!, with: self.psa, callFromBackgroundRefresh: true)
            AppViewModel.transferCarStateToWatch(newCarState!, via: self.connectivityManager)
        }
    } catch let ex {
        newCarState = nil
        occuredEx = ex
    }
    // Always refresh Token asynchronously when running background thread.
    // You never know when iOS schedules the refresh, so always refresh if you have the possibility!
    // ### AND HERE THE PROBLEM BEGINS! ###
    try? self.psa.refreshToken(fromBackgroundThread: true)
    if newCarState != nil || occuredEx != nil {
        DispatchQueue.background(task: {
            self.delegate?.newCarStateFromBackgroundRefresh(newCarState, error: occuredEx)
        })
    }
}
```

Refresh begins (within my API-Class):

```
func refreshToken(fromBackgroundThread: Bool = false) throws {
    if self.accessToken == nil {
        throw PSAErrorModel(code: -1, debug: "refreshToken", message: "Not signed in.")
    }
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
        "refresh_token": self.accessToken!.refresh_token
    ]
    if fromBackgroundThread {
        // This is called when refreshing the token from app background.
        self.acquireTokenAsync(parameters: parameters)
    } else {
        // This is a "synchronous" call, using DispatchSemaphore.
        // But this only fires when the app is active and it works great.
        self.accessToken = try self.acquireToken(parameters: parameters)
    }
}
```

Calling my URLSession.background wrapper:

```
private func acquireTokenAsync(parameters: [String : Any]) {
    let urlSession = BackgroundURLRequest()
    urlSession.delegate = self
    // Same URLRequest as in foreground refresh, so thats not different.
    let request = self.createUrlRequestForTokenAcquiry(parameters: parameters)
    urlSession.startDataTask(with: request)
}
```

And now we get to the problem:

```
func startDataTask(with request: URLRequest) {
    // Until here every breakpoint gets hit.
    // But when breaking here and pressing "resume", none of the delegate functions
    // are fired UNTIL I BRING THE APP TO FRONT. Without bringing the app to front,
    // the delegate functions will NEVER fire. And that's my problem.
    session.dataTask(with: request).resume()
}
```

For better understanding, here is my "BackgroundURLRequest":

```
// These delegates are implemented in my API-Class. So when the request finishes, the received OAuth-Token will be stored.
protocol BackgroundURLRequestDelegate: AnyObject {
    func backgroundUrlRequestFinished(session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, receivedData: Data)

    func backgroundUrlRequestFailed(session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, error: Error?)
}

class BackgroundURLRequest: NSObject {
    static let shared = BackgroundURLRequest()

    private static let identifier = "<MyIdentifier>"

    weak var delegate: BackgroundURLRequestDelegate?

    private var session: URLSession!

    var savedCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: BackgroundURLRequest.identifier)
        configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
        configuration.isDiscretionary = false
        configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true
        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }

    func startDataTask(with request: URLRequest) {
        // Until here every breakpoint gets hit.
        // But when breaking here and pressing "resume", none of the delegate functions
        // are fired UNTIL I BRING THE APP TO FRONT. Without bringing the app to front,
        // the delegate functions will NEVER fire. And that's my problem.
        session.dataTask(with: request).resume()
    }
}

extension BackgroundURLRequest: URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.savedCompletionHandler?()
            self.savedCompletionHandler = nil
        }
    }
}

extension BackgroundURLRequest: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print("BackgroundURLRequest ERROR:\n\(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No description.")")
        self.delegate?.backgroundUrlRequestFailed(session: session, task: task, error: error)
    }
}

extension BackgroundURLRequest: URLSessionDataDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        self.delegate?.backgroundUrlRequestFinished(session: session, dataTask: dataTask, receivedData: data)
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't need to use `URLSession.background` here - Presumably the amount of data you have to transfer is reasonably small.  background transfers are used for scenarios where you need to upload or download large amounts of data that may take some time (uploading photos for example).  You should [edit] your question to show the relevant code, but it should be something like "if token has expired then request new token.  Fetch data with token".  Make sure you don't call the completion handler to end your background refresh too soon.

Comment: The best would be to send a notification that will open the app when user tap it.

Comment: @Paulw11
I'll post some code in a bit.

Comment: @PtitXav That's not what should be done… The background refresh is used to update what is displayed on the watch.

Comment: @Paulw11 Snippets added. Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't need any of that background stuff. Assuming that your network operations take less than 30 seconds you can use normal url session operations.

Comment: @Paulw11 It definetly takes less than 30 sec. But no matter how I do the POST, the thread stops at dataTask.resume() when in background. It only continues if I bring the app back to front. With GET it works like a charm. I really don't understand why and everytime I think about it I don't see what I'm doing wrong (according to the documentation and everything else I read on the internet).

Comment: Have you tried it with a regular URLSession.datatask?  You don't need the background session and delegates and all of that.  Make sure you don't call the completion handler for your background task until you are done.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I tried that just now. - Same problem. DataTask gets created and when in background .resume() is the last thing I can get. It only continues if I bring the app to front.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't managing your background task properly.  Edit your question to show that code; How do you handle the background refresh event.

Comment: @Paulw11 I reverted my code so that I don't use the BackgroundURLRequest anymore and found out that everything works when I put everything in `performBackgroundRefresh()` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`. Now GET and POST are working from background. - But I'm pretty sure that this isn't the most elegant solution. To answer your last question: I only run the code within `performBackgroundRefresh()` when it gets called by the system.

Comment: What I meant was "show the code" where you handle the background refresh event. The symptoms you describe sound like you aren't managing your background refresh event lifecycle correctly. ios thinks you are done when you aren't

Comment: @Paulw11 In the main scene I schedule the background task when the scene phase changes to `.background`. And when iOS starts my background task the scene modifier `.backgroundTask()` gets fired in which I call `await viewModel.performBackgroundRefresh()`. That's it. And as I mentioned, since using `DispatchQueue.main.async` for everything that's done within `performBackgroundRefresh()` GET and POST are working and my watch app gets updates (I added a counter on my watch app so that I can observe it).

Comment: Ok, so I was a bit confused. When you said you were using a background refresh, I assumed you were using one of the actual background refresh services, such as BGTaskscheduler, that iOS provides to schedule background execution for some future time. . Simply executing code when your app transitions to the background doesn't actually set up background execution so your network task is suspended. You can use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpiratiinHandler`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `dataTask` method with `resume`, that returns immediately, and thus the `.backgroundTask` closure will return prematurely, before the request finishes.

Ideally, I would advise:

- Do not use background `URLSession` (which requires delegate operation). Use standard session.
- Having done that, you can now [`await session.data(for:delegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data), which will not return until the request finishes.

If you do that, your `await` within the `backgroundTask` should not continue until the network request is done.